# How send a mail over gmail

Tags: android

i am getting data from edit text and try to send it over a  gmail id but i am getting this "No apps perform this action" please tell me where i am doing wrong because i am new in android 
thanks

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.send)
        {
            String name = objName.getText().toString();
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "sgrpatel22@gmail.com"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Mail :"));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.send)
        {
            String name = objName.getText().toString();
            Intent email= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.setType("text/plain");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "sgrpatel22@gmail.com"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
            startActivity(email);   

        }
    }
```

Comment: now this code sending me another screen where i have to write email id and message..

Comment: thats right, should be prefilled couse putextra Feature. You have to click the send button after

Comment: that's not prefilled we have to write email id and message again.

Comment: You should try on your real device, im using  this code in my app and its working flawless ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK Simulator, then you may not be having GMail app installed on it.